# Javascript How to call another function within a variable object function

Tags: javascript

i want to call the isAuthenticated() method within the logout function.

(Im not sure what you call this layout its like a variable object containing functions)

```
var svc = {
    logout: function () {
        isAuthenticated() // Call isAuthenticated function here
    },
    login: function () {},
    isAuthenticated: function () {}
}
```

Simply calling `isAuthenticated()` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`svc` is an object, where are logout & `isAuthenticated` are methods.You can use `this` to call the function.Here `this` points to the `svc` object

```js
var svc = {
  logout: function() {
    this.isAuthenticated() // Call isAuthenticated function here
  },

  login: function() {


  },

  isAuthenticated: function() {
    console.log('isAuthenticated called');
  }
}
svc.logout()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to it.

```
 var svc = {
                logout: function () {
                    this.isAuthenticated() // Call isAuthenticated function here
                },

                login: function (){


                },

                isAuthenticated: function () {
                    console.log("Test");
                }
}

svc.logout();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
this.isAuthenticated();
```

You need to use "this" to call other members of the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript object variables and functions are accessed by prefixing the object name followed by the variable/function name.

In your case, you can call isAuthenticated() like this:

```
svc.isAuthenticated()
```

Answer (score 0):

You nee to use the reference of that object `svc` `-->` `this.isAuthenticated()`

```js
var svc = {
  logout: function() {
    this.isAuthenticated()
  },

  login: function() {},

  isAuthenticated: function() {
    console.log("Is Authenticated!?")
  }
}

svc.logout();
```

Another alternative is creating a function and declaring a variable, this way you will be able to call it directly as follow:

```js
var svc = function() {
  var isAuthenticated = function() {
    console.log("Is Authenticated!?");
  }
  
  this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
  
  this.logout = function() {
    isAuthenticated()
  };
  
  this.login = function() {};
}

new svc().logout();
new svc().isAuthenticated();
```